# LC circuit problem

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage, inductance

I am currently  working on a LC circuit problem where there were given this question that I couldn't understand which is : theoretically justify the shape of the curve (the spring curve) by establishing the relationship between the voltage of the inductor $U_{L}$ and the charge on the capacitor $q_{}$ and by that they mean : $ \bbox[pink,5px]
{     U_{L}=L\frac{di}{dt}=L\frac{dq^2}{dt^2}}$

and this is the curve that I am supposed to look at :

[image]

N.B : specifically I am looking at an electrical circuit consisting of :

-a capacitor with capacitance c ,

-an inductor with inductance L and negligible
internal resistance .

- $U_{L}$ means $ V_{L}$ : the voltage of the inductor .